# How do I take a value out of a Maybe monad in ramda-fantasy?

Tags: javascript, monads, ramda.js, ramda-fantasy

I want to have a pipe that does some operations on a Maybe, and want to return its value at last. Currently I am doing:

```
const data = Maybe(5)
pipe(
  map(add(1)),
  ... other operations
  y => y.getOrElse([])
)(data)
```

Is there any cleaner way out?

Comment: No, I think that's it. However, replacing `Maybe a` with `[a]` doesn't give you much. It is just another representation of computations that may not produce a result. I would stick with the `Maybe` abstraction. Btw, `Maybe` is an odd name for a value constructor. It should be `Just`.

Comment: @ftor, I would assume that "...other operations" return a meaningful array, not just an array wrapping that one value.  In that case, `[]` might be the appropriate default, as it often is for arrays.

Comment: I agree with @ftor that there's nothing substantially better, and that you might be better off sticking with the Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement would be to create a pointfree helper function

```
const getOrElse = (defaultValue) => (m) => m.getOrElse(defaultValue);
```